# using await in node js but it seem doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I want to show 'result' before 'myJson' but it show  'myJson'   before 'result' in console.log. pls help me.

```
async function show() {
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "root",
    password: "aaaaaaaa",
    database: "doto"
  })
  var myJson = null;
  var sql = "select * from task_list";
  result = "[";
  con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        result = result + '{ detail:' + row.details + ", status:" + row.status + ", subject:" + row.subject + '},';
      });
      console.log("result" + result);
    });
  });
  result = await result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
  result = await result + ']';
  myJson = await JSON.stringify(result);
  await console.log("myJson" + myJson);
  return await myJson;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use `await` with expressions and syncronous functions. Check the documentation on async functions. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) To quote the docs, "An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value."

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question would be that you are using `await` totally wrong... `await` is meant to be used with Asynchronous requests. ie: calls to the IO or FS. You should most likely look at some MDN documentation in regards to the usage, but something that will help you solve this problem that you are having here would be adding the code below the `conn.connect()` method into the `con.query()` callback. This would be the easiest solution. One other way that you could accomplish this is to wrap `conn.connect()` in a promise and resolve the result in the `conn.query()` callback. Examples are going to be below:

Callback:

```
const conn = mysql.connect()
conn.connect((err, connection) => {
    connection.query("query", (err, results) => {
        // do all stuff with results here
    })
})
```

Promise:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.connect((err, connection) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        connection.query("query", (err, results) => {
             if (err) return reject(err)
             resolve(results)
        })
    })
})
```

Something like this would work